# Can xcworkspace propagate or share Package.resolved with its sub xcprojects?

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager, matlab-spm

We have multiple apps who are sharing dependencies.

We develop these apps in a workspace to reduce time spend resolving packages, compiling etc.

The issue is that the Package.resolved is being resolved in the xcworkspace. So when our CI-CD build each individual app (it works on a .xcproject basis) it doesn't have the correct Package.resolved file.

Currently our solutions are

- Change CI/CD to build the .xcworkspace instead
- Manually open each .xcproject and resolve
- Run swift package update in the dependencies, then (script) copy it into each project

They all kinda work, but I wonder if there is a proper way to keep using the xcworkspace and simply automatically get the resolved file into the xcprojects.

Thank you